# Is there any alternative for Azure Logic apps? opensource would be better

Tags: automation, workflow, azure-logic-apps

Currently I'm using Azure Logic apps to sync the changes to different 3rd parties.
But it's too expensive when there are massive requests/messages.

The key features:

1. MQ connector, which can be used as trigger.
2. HTTP processor, used to issue HTTP requests.
3. Parse json response.
4. Possibility to check the history.

I've done some research of Apache Nifi.
My feeling is it's not very user friendly and quite old school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: There is a new [Logic Apps Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare) offering that runs Logic Apps in a regular App Service Plan like a Web App which falls in between the Consumption and Integration Service Environment offerings.

---

One close open-source option that I know of is [n8n](https://n8n.io/).

But you could also explore the [fixed pricing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#fixed-pricing-model) ([Integration Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview#dedicated-versus-multi-tenant)) that logic apps offer, which is charged by the hour instead of based on the volume coming. Depending on the volume fluctuations, you can scale up more units as required.

Also, a completely new (in [preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/) currently) way to develop and run logic app workflows was announced, which introduces a new [pricing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-stateful-stateless-workflows-visual-studio-code#pricing-model) (same as app service or premium plan of functions).

This is introduces a [docker-based deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-stateful-stateless-workflows-visual-studio-code#deploy-to-docker-container) which allows running your logic apps anywhere too.

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable info. I will check in detail

Answer (score 0):

[Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) can be used for your requirements.

Apache NiFi is an easy to use, powerful, and reliable system to process and distribute data.

It has:

1. ConsumeMQTT processor which subscribes to a topic and receives messages from an MQTT broker.
2. InvokeHTTP processor which can interact with a configurable HTTP Endpoint.
3. Numerous json processors.
4. Data Provenance feature which tracks dataflow from beginning to end.